# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

As part of a form I have in view:

```
<%= form_for(@invitation, method: :post, url: addinvite_path) do |f| %>
  ...
  <label for="email", title="email"></label>
  <%= email_field_tag :email, nil, placeholder: 'Email', autocomplete: 'off', required: true %><br>
  ...
```

The invitations controller method that processes a submission of the form:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(email: params[:email])
  ...
```

Submitting the form produces an error pointing to the `@user` line:

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "id"

I'm not sure what causes this error. Placing the `debugger` before the `@user` line confirms there's a value for `params[:email]`. But also in the `debugger` if I enter `User.find(email: params[:email])` it returns the above enter. What could be causing the error?

Comment: Try using with `find_by`. `@user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "id"

By default `find` will look for `id`. You need to use `find_by`

```
@user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `find_by` instead of `find`

```
def create
  @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the updated copy:

## For Single Record

```
def create
  @user = User.where(email: params[:email]).first
end
```

## For Multi Records

```
 def create
   @user = User.where(email: params[:email])
```